# converting an array into multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array as :

```
Array
(
    [d26f8828-8362-7d78-49db-2abfd44608f7] => 2cdc40f5-3e99-72b2-1bc8-9ec30496106c
    [c464b8ff-adfc-b901-1ec3-77f119a896c5] => b79c98de-07ba-9c53-d6a4-2de07eec9537
)
```

how can I convert it into multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [d26f8828-8362-7d78-49db-2abfd44608f7] => 2cdc40f5-3e99-72b2-1bc8-9ec30496106c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [c464b8ff-adfc-b901-1ec3-77f119a896c5] => b79c98de-07ba-9c53-d6a4-2de07eec9537
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $newArray = array();
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
   $newArray[] = array($key =>value);
  }
```

`$newArray` has what you need.